# Why getting Uncaught TypeError: BOOMR.hasSentPageLoadBeacon is not a function on Firefox only?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, boomerang

I have a website which is live and I am using BOOMR to do something with my data. However. on Prod env for firefox browser, it is showing this below error on consoleUncaught TypeError:

```
    BOOMR.hasSentPageLoadBeacon is not a function
```

But, it's working fine on chrome and other browsers. Also, for non prod envs all browsers are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds as though the BOOMR object may not be loaded or at least is not loaded correctly or fully.

In the browser Console look to see what is returned when you type `BOOMR` and press enter.  If the BOOMR object isn't there then you'll need to investigate what could be blocking it.  Since this is browser and environment specific, I recommend looking for JS errors in the console fist.

Another possibility is that the BOOMR object is not loaded early enough and whatever code is calling the `BOOMR.hasSentPageLoadBeacon` is trying to execute the method before the object is loaded.

I'd also ensure that you are using the latest version of the BOOR library to make best use of its latest features and compatibility updates.